# Generalized path cover problem in DAG

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-algorithms, np-hardness, np-complete, directed-acyclic-graph

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed acyclic graph. Two vertices is transitive if there is a directed path between them. A Path Cover for a Set of Transitive Pairs (PCSTP) is a set of directed paths such that every pair of transitive vertices belongs to at least one path. The minimum PCSTP problem consists of finding a PCSTP for G having the least number of paths. Is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292165/find-a-minimum-set-of-paths-that-cover-all-pairs-of-dependent-vertices